# SQL (Access) Select records that are not in the second table by condition and non-unique id

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, having

I have two tables in MS Access, with non-unique id's, dates and qty:

TABLE_IN

| id | date | qty | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.09.2022 | 1 | Item_1 |
| 2 | 12.10.2022 | 1 | Item_2 |
| 1 | 10.11.2022 | 2 | Item_1 |
| 2 | 15.11.2022 | 1 | Item_2 |

TABLE_OUT

| id | date | qty | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15.09.2022 | 1 | Item_1 |
| 2 | 13.11.2022 | 1 | Item_2 |
| 1 | 18.11.2022 | 2 | Item_1 |

I need to select records that are IN (first table), but not OUT (second table) by dates (where 'in' date is less than 'out') and id`s.

Expected output:

| id | date | qty | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 15.11.2022 | 1 | Item_2 |

Required output data is id and qty (either it can be SUM of all qty's) that match selection.

I'm trying to use join, like this (and many other different variants):

```
SELECT [TABLE_IN].*
  FROM [TABLE_IN]
  LEFT JOIN [TABLE_OUT]
    ON [TABLE_IN].id = [TABLE_OUT].id
 WHERE [TABLE_OUT].id IS NULL
    OR ([TABLE_OUT].date < [TABLE_IN].date 
   AND  [TABLE_IN].id    = [TABLE_OUT].id)
```

But it does not gives the needed result:

| id | date | qty | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18.11.2022 | 2 | Item_1 |
| 2 | 15.11.2022 | 1 | Item_2 |

Maybe I need to use HAVING COUNT instructions.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this suits your needs:

```
SELECT table_in.* 
FROM table_in
LEFT JOIN table_out ON table_out.id = table_in.id
AND table_in.date < table_out.date
WHERE table_out.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes, it works as i need! Thanks a lot!:)
I didn`t know that between ON and WHERE more than one statement is available :))

Comment: Your welcome!, If you don't mind marking as accepted =D